# Bitbucket pipeline not running custom manual deploy correctly

Tags: environment-variables, bitbucket, jira, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a custom call in my Bitbucket pipeline called "manualStagingDeploy." I have repository environment variables defined for my development environment and deployment env vars for the test, staging, and production environments.

The problem is that when I manually run the manualStagingDeploy pipeline from inside of Bitbucket, it only references the env vars for the dev environment from my repo variables. The documentation says that environment-specific deployment variables (e.g., "staging") should override the default repository variables (for my dev env).

Here is my bitbucket_pipeline.yml file:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Preparing to deploy
        script:
          - npm install
          - echo "Deployment starting"
  pull-requests:
    '**':
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Staging
          deployment: staging
          script:
            - chmod +x scripts/staging.sh
            - ./scripts/staging.sh
  branches:
    releases/*:
      - step:
          name: Build
          script:
            - npm install
            - npm run build
          artifacts:
            - build/**
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Testing
          deployment: test
          script:
            - chmod +x scripts/test.sh
            - ./scripts/test.sh
      - step:
          name: Auto Deploy to Staging
          deployment: staging
          script:
            - chmod +x scripts/staging.sh
            - ./scripts/staging.sh
  custom:
    manualStagingDeploy:
      - step:
          name: Manual Deploy to Staging
          deployment: staging
          script:
            - chmod +x scripts/staging.sh
            - ./scripts/staging.sh
  tags:
    'v*':
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Production
          deployment: production
          script:
            - chmod +x scripts/production.sh
            - ./scripts/production.sh
```

I expect to see the deployment env vars I've defined for staging to be used when I run the manualStagingDeploy however it is only using the dev vars. Below is the output from the pipeline log showing that it is in the actual staging.sh script (the first line with "Deployihg to staging") but referencing the repo dev vars (the remaining lines in the log).

```
=== Deploying to 'staging'...

i  deploying hosting

i  hosting[app-dev]: beginning deploy...

i  hosting[app-dev]: found 27 files in .output/public

i  hosting: upload complete

✔  hosting[app-dev]: file upload complete

i  hosting[app-dev]: finalizing version...

✔  hosting[app-dev]: version finalized

i  hosting[app-dev]: releasing new version...

✔  hosting[app-dev]: release complete

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/app-staging/overview

Hosting URL: https://app-dev.web.app

&&&&&& finished firebase deploy &&&&&&
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I see 3 `deployment: staging` steps in your file, but that's supposed to be forbidden by bitbucket pipelines. I don't understand why bitbucket isn't refusing to run your file at all.

Comment: Is that the case? So if I have different conditions that require deployment to a staging env, like on push to release or if I want to push something manually, I can't have multiple deploys?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like it's actually not a problem with the pipeline but rather a problem with the firebase.json file. An explicit environment was added to the config for the dev environment, causing all deploys to push to dev.